# Unable to find/add ordered test item to my project in Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise MSTest Selenium Unit Tests C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, mstest

I am unable to find and add the Ordered Test item to my project (MSTest based Selenium Tests in C#) in Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise Edition. I have tried the following steps to find and add the Ordered Test item to my project but I don't see the Ordered Test item. Please see the screenshot below.

[Solution Explorer -> Right Click Project -> Add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7SVZ.png)

[Visual Studio -> Right Click Project -> Add -> New Item -> Test (Visual C# Items)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMizO.png)

Answer (score 8):

Turns out MSTest V2 doesn't support ordered tests. That is the reason I am unable to find the ordered test option. Refer to the link below for more details:

[MSTestv2 does not support orderedTests #25](https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx/issues/25)

[Cannot run ordered tests since upgrading to new MSTestV2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/075a0e32-7f3c-4ead-889b-9d8a0b8ed5a5/cannot-run-ordered-tests-since-upgrading-to-new-mstestv2?forum=vsunittest)

Comment: Way to go backwards, microsoft